# How can I add to DB new created Polygon?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, android

I'm new to LeafLet and I'm trying to understand power of LeafLet for mapping..

Question is simple, let's say I've created a new object(e.g. polygon)

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;
drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                });
```

Here, how can I pass my new object like parameter ?

I am working on android and I have to send new object to android..

One more question.. What is type of new created polygon ? How can i check it from JavaScript ?

After sending new object, I'll add to DB..